# How add multiple tile layer to google map

Tags: java, google-maps, tiles

Need help for adding multiple custom layers over google map. 
I have script:

```
function newMap(id,lon,lat,zoom,mapstart){
        var nmap = new GMap2(document.getElementById(id),{backgroundColor: "Silver"});
        nmap.addControl(new GLargeMapControl(), new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_TOP_LEFT, new GSize(8,37)));
        nmap.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
        nmap.addControl(new GScaleControl());
        nmap.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        nmap.enableContinuousZoom();

        var GMapTypeOptions = new Object({minResolution: 9, maxResolution: 18});

        var copyCollection = new GCopyrightCollection('');
        var copyright = new GCopyright(1, new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-89,-179), new GLatLng(89,179)),0,"<font color=white><B>Demo <a href=http://mysite.com target=_blank><font color=white>mysite.com</font></a><BR>demo <a href=http://www.maps.com target=_blank><font color=white>maps.com</font></a>, <a href=http://www.pobeda-info.by target=_blank><font color=white>pobeda-info.by</font></a></B><BR></font>");
        copyCollection.addCopyright(copyright);

        var WWIILayer = new GTileLayer(copyCollection, 9,18,{tileUrlTemplate:'http://mymap.com/AerialWWII/Z{Z}/{Y}/{X}.jpg'});
        //http://46.182.27.171

        var WWIIMap = new GMapType([WWIILayer], new GMercatorProjection(22), "WWII", {});
        nmap.addMapType(WWIIMap);
        var WWIIHybMap = new GMapType([WWIILayer, G_HYBRID_MAP.getTileLayers()[1]], new GMercatorProjection(22), "Show streets",GMapTypeOptions);
        nmap.addMapType(WWIIHybMap);

        var hierarchy = new GHierarchicalMapTypeControl();
        hierarchy.addRelationship(WWIIMap, WWIIHybMap, false);

        if (mapstart==1) {
            nmap.setCenter( new GLatLng(lon,lat), zoom, WWIIMap);
        } else {
            nmap.setCenter( new GLatLng(lon,lat), zoom, G_SATELLITE_MAP);
        }
        nmap.addControl(hierarchy);
        return nmap;

}
```

Work great with one layer "WWII"! Need add second custom layer "WWII - 2", maybe somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Google Maps JS v2 code. Have you thought about upgrading your code to v3? https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Once you are on v3 a lot more sample code will make sense, and people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Tnx Brett for answer. Try upgrade